# Add field in product.pricelist.item in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-view

I want to add `selection field` like below:

```
class product_pricelist_item1(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.pricelist.item'

    x_type = fields.Selection(selection=[('sample', 'Sample'),('moq', 'MOQ'),('others', 'Others')],string="Choices")
```

in `product.pricelist.item` form. I am writing XML code like below:

```
        <record id="product_pricelist_item_form_view_with_code" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">product.pricelist.item.form</field>
            <field name="model">product.pricelist.item</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_pricelist_item_form_view" />
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="min_quantity" position="after">
                    <field name="x_type"/>
                </field>
            </field>
        </record>
```

But when i open pricelist it is giving me an error like this:

`Odoo Server Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\http.py" 599, line in _handle_exception
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 636, in dispatch
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 315, in _call_function
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 308, in checked_call
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 887, in __call__
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 465, in response_wrap
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 971, in call_kw
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 963, in _call_kw
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 232, in wrapper
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 3173, in read
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 230, in wrapper
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 3219, in read
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 5684, in __getitem__
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\fields.py", line 807, in __get__
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\fields.py", line 914, in determine_value
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\fields.py", line 869, in compute_value
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\fields.py", line 859, in _compute_value
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 230, in wrapper
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 398, in new_api
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\openerp\addons\product\pricelist.py", line   331, in _get_pricelist_item_name_price
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\fields.py", line 807, in __get__
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\fields.py", line 905, in determine_value
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 230, in wrapper
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 3278, in _prefetch_field
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 230, in wrapper
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 3208, in read
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 230, in wrapper
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 3346, in _read_from_database
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\sql_db.py", line 139, in wrapper
    File "C:\Odoo 9.0-20151122\server\.\openerp\sql_db.py", line 215, in execute
    ProgrammingError: column product_pricelist_item.x_type does not exist
   LINE 1: ...duct_pricelist_item"."create_uid" as "create_uid","product_p...`

Comment: did you restart the server and upgraded your module??

Comment: during updation it gives me no error, but when i goes to open pricelist item form then it gives me this error...

Comment: could you please provide me with your add-on directory name & add your  descriptor file __openerp__.py to your question to help

Comment: Did you added that py file into the __init__.py ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion `kifcaliph` i was updating wrong module...! Thanks all...

Answer (score 1):

When extending a model, if you want to add possible values to a selection field, you may use the selection_add keyword argument:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    _inherits = 'some.model'
    type = fields.Selection(selection_add=[('b', 'B'), ('c', 'C')])
```

[reference](http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html)

Try the following

```
class product_pricelist_item(models.Model):
    _inherit='product.pricelist.item'

    x_type= fields.Selection(selection_add=[('b', 'B')])
```

and for xml

```
  <record id='product_product_pricelist_item_form_view' model='ir.ui.view'>
    <field name="model">product.pricelist.item</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_pricelist_item_form_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <form position="after">
        <field name="x_type" widget="radio"/>
      </form>
    </field>
  </record>
```

this should work.